# Received a label value of 3298 which is outside the valid range of [0, 2)

Tags: python-3.x

Received a label value of 3298 which is outside the valid range of [0, 2). I want to train my model but I came across this error. your help will be highly appreciated.

I'm trying to train the model using tensorflow 2 and I created layers, now the model throw some errors.
**X_train_normalized.shape**  this is the shape for X_train

```
(23, 11)

**X_train_normalized.ndim** this is ndimfor X_train
2


Model: "sequential_3"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
dense_18 (Dense)             (None, 16)                192       
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_15 (Batc (None, 16)                64        
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_15 (Dropout)         (None, 16)                0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_19 (Dense)             (None, 16)                272       
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_16 (Batc (None, 16)                64        
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_16 (Dropout)         (None, 16)                0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_20 (Dense)             (None, 126)               2142      
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_17 (Batc (None, 126)               504       
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_17 (Dropout)         (None, 126)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_21 (Dense)             (None, 160)               20320     
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_18 (Batc (None, 160)               640       
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_18 (Dropout)         (None, 160)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_22 (Dense)             (None, 10)                1610      
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_19 (Dropout)         (None, 10)                0         
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_19 (Batc (None, 10)                40        
_________________________________________________________________
dense_23 (Dense)             (None, 2)                 22        
=================================================================
Total params: 25,870
Trainable params: 25,214
Non-trainable params: 656



numDim = X_train_normalized.shape[1]
dnnModel = tf.keras.Sequential([
    layers.Dense(16, activation = 'relu', input_shape =(numDim,)),
    layers.BatchNormalization(),
    layers.Dropout(0.3),
    layers.Dense(16, activation = 'relu'),
    layers.BatchNormalization(),
    layers.Dropout(0.3),
    layers.Dense(126, activation = 'relu'),
    layers.BatchNormalization(),
    layers.Dropout(0.5),
    layers.Dense(160, activation = 'relu'),
    layers.BatchNormalization(),
    layers.Dropout(0.5),
    layers.Dense(10, activation = 'relu'),
    layers.Dropout(0.1),
    layers.BatchNormalization(),
    layers.Dense(2)
    
])
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.01)
dnnModel.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True), metrics=['accuracy'])


**Error**

**dnnModel.fit(X_train_normalized, y_train, epochs=100)**

Epoch 1/100
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-86-47e282adff89> in <module>
----> 1 dnnModel.fit(X_train_normalized, y_train, epochs=100)
      2 #last results accuracy shows training accuracy

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py in `enter code here`fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_batch_size, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
   1181                 _r=1):
   1182               callbacks.on_train_batch_begin(step)
-> 1183               tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
   1184               if data_handler.should_sync:
   1185                 context.async_wait()

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwds)
    887 
    888       with OptionalXlaContext(self._jit_compile):
--> 889         result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
    890 
    891       new_tracing_count = self.experimental_get_tracing_count()

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py in _call(self, *args, **kwds)enter code here
    948         # Lifting succeeded, so variables are initialized and we can run the
    949         # stateless function.
--> 950         return self._stateless_fn(*args, **kwds)
    951     else:
    952       _, _, _, filtered_flat_args = \

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
   3021       (graph_function,
   3022        filtered_flat_args) = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
-> 3023     return graph_function._call_flat(
   3024         filtered_flat_args, captured_inputs=graph_function.captured_inputs)  # pylint: disable=protected-access
   3025 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py in _call_flat(self, args, captured_inputs, cancellation_manager)
   1958         and executing_eagerly):
   1959       # No tape is watching; skip to running the function.
-> 1960       return self._build_call_outputs(self._inference_function.call(
   1961           ctx, args, cancellation_manager=cancellation_manager))
   1962     forward_backward = self._select_forward_and_backward_functions(

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py in call(self, ctx, args, cancellation_manager)
    589       with _InterpolateFunctionError(self):
    590         if cancellation_manager is None:
--> 591           outputs = execute.execute(
    592               str(self.signature.name),
    593               num_outputs=self._num_outputs,

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\execute.py in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     57   try:
     58     ctx.ensure_initialized()
---> 59     tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
     60                                         inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
     61   except core._NotOkStatusException as e:

InvalidArgumentError:  Received a label value of 3298 which is outside the valid range of [0, 2).  Label values: 1164 1877 3113 1432 2582 2849 1612 2143 2232 2120 3065 2692 1000 2936 1976 1341 2407 1300 3205 1770 1074 3298 980
     [[node sparse_categorical_crossentropy/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits (defined at <ipython-input-86-47e282adff89>:1) ]] [Op:__inference_train_function_7420]

Function call stack:
train_function
```

Comment: Please edit your post so the question comes clear.

Comment: @MarcelHofgesang, Thanks I managed to get the answer, can you kindly help me with Using percentage as dependent variable (target variable), grouping percentages or sort them in this format . 0 > 20% = 1, 20% >40% = 2 ?